# Is there a way to speed up the boot to the first menu on the Live CD?

Tags: boot, live-cd

Is there a way to speedup the boot to the menu where you choose the livecd or instalation withou cutting your wrist first?

11.10 version is too slow compared with the 8.10 or 9.04 boot and not to mention the OS with daily use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can press the DownArrow at the start of the Ubuntu live cd and it will show you the old Live cd menu and there you can select to try or install Ubuntu. Doing so you will save a lot of time.